# onstartcommand method of service class is called repeatedally when startservice once trigred from activity class

Tags: android, service

i m following tutorial link http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/07/14/ http request -call-repeatedly-service-android but i m bit confusing about following code which make http call repeatedally so where onstart() method or onstartcommand() is called repeatedally once its start thread mythread.start(); is finished or due to flag check in onstart() method.so, onstart() method is repeated once it's started thread is finished or it's return to onstart() when thread started is finished. plz, let me  clear.thanks in advance.

following is code->>

```
package com.coderzheaven.pack;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyService extends Service{

    private static String TAG = MyService.class.getSimpleName();
    private MyThread mythread;
    public boolean isRunning = false;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        <span id="IL_AD9" class="IL_AD">return</span> null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");     
        mythread  = new MyThread();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
        if(!isRunning){
            mythread.interrupt();
            mythread.stop();
        }       
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId); 
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
        if(!isRunning){
            mythread.start();
            isRunning = true;
        }
    }

    public void readWebPage(){
          HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
          HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://google.com");
          // Get the response
          ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
          String response_str = null;
          try {
             response_str = client.execute(request, responseHandler);
             if(!response_str.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                 Log.d(TAG, "Got Response");
             }
          } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
    }

    class MyThread extends Thread{
        static final long DELAY = 3000;
        @Override
        public void run(){          
            while(isRunning){
                Log.d(TAG,"Running");
                try {                   
                    readWebPage();
                    Thread.sleep(DELAY);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    isRunning = false;
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: stop Thread after getting response from server using `         isRunning = false;`

Comment: hello sir my query is mythred.start() which is trigged from onstart() method of service which is get called thread i.e run() method every 3 second of delay. how is done that way due to flag check or once thread is completed it's return to onstart() method  and it's again start the thread or onstart method itself return once thread is completed i m not getting that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onstart method is called once. while loop is repeating that(readWebPage() ) function and to stop the thread after getting responce form server just give false value to isRunnble variable in readWebPage() method